# Is it possible to send a file attachment (txt) from iphone via email?

Tags: iphone, email, attachment

I saw two related questions about this topic - one has an old link in an answer and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389655/iphone-email-attachment) doesn't have an answer (right now).

(I am new to iphone development)

I want to create a file from my app, then send that file as an attachment.  Is this possible?

I'm not looking for someone to send me teh codez - just SPECIFIC references and links.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's part of the new Message UI Framework in >2

[MFMailComposeViewController addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMailComposeViewController/addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:)