# Embed images into an HTML email with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: html, ios, xamarin

I am trying to send an email from an iOS device (Using Xamarin) in an HTML format with images embedded in the body of the email.

Some solutions that I found online suggest to use an approach similar to the one shown here:

```
NSData ImgData = UIImage.FromFile(FileName).AsJPEG();
string img64baseStr = ImgData.GetBase64EncodedString(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None);
string srcStr = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", img64baseStr);
```

Using the code above I can see the pictures properly in the iOS Email client. However, when the email is sent I can't see the images on the receiving side. 
There are other setbacks to this approach, but I can avoid getting into those in more details at this point.

I have also tried using the images as resources in the project. However, when I reference the pictures directly in the HTML in this form:

```
<img src="Pic1.png" width="700" height="500" alt=""/>
```

the linkage is broken and the email is missing the images.

How can I properly reference resource images in an HTML email?

Comment: You should share some code so we might see what's wrong with your implementation. After all, there are multiple ways to send emails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed an image in the HTML body of an email in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397775/how-to-embed-an-image-in-the-html-body-of-an-email-in-ios)

Comment: @SushiHangover possible dupe, but there are no Xamarin examples or answers in that question.

Comment: @SushiHangover, Thanks. The link you sent is in Objective-C. I am looking for a xamarin solution.

Comment: @JAL Easy enough to convert a few lines of code between languages...

Comment: @JayJacobs Show what you have tried in C# and what is not actually working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like the approach described above, of converting the data object to a base64 string is deprecated by most email clients for security reasons and the email client will block Dada URIs that are arriving this way.

I found the question posted in the link below to be helpful for understanding why things weren't working for me:

> [base64 encoded images in email signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures/9110164#9110164)

Specifically refer to the answer posted by @Shadow2531 and the discussion that followed it.

Finally, I was able to achieve what I wanted using the MailKit package that is available on NuGet. 
The package has a pretty comprehensive documentation. Specifically for the problem I was trying to solve, take a look at this page:

> http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/CreatingMessages.htm

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! Helps a lot!